# Material transition FAB to activity - Activity is still present for a second when transitioning back

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-components-android

I am trying to get a material transition to work from a FAB in Activity A to Activity B and back. Its currently working but with a slight issue. When I click on a FAB it expands to the Activity B using material transition with no issues. But when I transition back from Activity B to Activity A, Activity B duplicates and is still present for a second during the transition and it takes a second for it to disappear fully.

Here is the guide I followed:

https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion

Specifically under the section, "Container transform examples" and under the subsection "Transition between Activities".

Here is what the issue I am facing looks like. Hopefully these images give a clear idea. In these images I am transitioning from Activity B to Activity A. This is where the problem is

[Here is Activity B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcftr.png)

[The back button is pressed and Activity B transforms back into the FAB in Activity A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5JzC.png)

[Now the FAB from Activity A is visible again but Activity B is still visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDM5L.png)

[Finally Activity B disappears and Activity A is visible again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O5nD.png)

As you can see once the back button is pressed Activity A should appear immediately but it still shows
Activity B for a second.

Here is what I have in my code which is basically just following the guide:

In Activity A in the onCreate method:

```
setExitSharedElementCallback(new MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback());
getWindow().setSharedElementsUseOverlay(false);

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And in the onClick of the FAB in Activity A:

```
FloatingActionButton newTaskButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.newTaskButton);

newTaskButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, newTaskButton, "shared_container");

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateNewTask.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1, options.toBundle());

            }
        });
```

And in the onCreate method of Activity B:

```
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setTransitionName("shared_container");
        
        setEnterSharedElementCallback(new MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback());
        
        MaterialContainerTransform transform = new MaterialContainerTransform();
        
        transform.addTarget(android.R.id.content);
        transform.setAllContainerColors(MaterialColors.getColor(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.attr.colorSurface));
        transform.setFitMode(MaterialContainerTransform.FIT_MODE_AUTO);
        transform.setDuration(550L);
        transform.setPathMotion(new MaterialArcMotion());
        transform.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
        transform.setScrimColor(Color.parseColor("#4AED93"));

        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transform);
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_task);
```

I have enabled window transitions for the theme

```
<!-- enable window content transitions -->
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```

I thought this might be an issue with the scrim color or container color but these dont affect
this particular issue. Can you guys advise?

Comment: I have just tested with your code, and I can't notice any visibility issue like you have said. This is how it looks for me. [ https://giphy.com/gifs/CSPskRtnD7hQnLW8M3 ] the delay is because of bad gif, works fine and smooth in device.

Comment: @Rajasekhar I tried this code with a very basic test app and it worked with no issues like you said. I guess the issue is in my current application somewhere.